# Character Encoding Issue on Ubuntu/Bash

Tags: bash, character-encoding, utf

I'd like to cat a Swedish txt file.

For special characters (like ä or é) I get back these characters: �.

eg.
�r han fr�n Apornas planet.

I have multiple files from multiple sources and some of them gives back the correct results, (Eg. Det här är fel!) some of them produces the above mentioned issue.

Based on that I'm pretty sure, that the issue is with the file's character (en)coding, but I just simply can't find how to encode the file at the command line.

I've tried:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 file.txt
```

and similars.
But I've ended up in an error message all the time.

Do you have any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `chardet file.txt`?

Comment: The most common encodings for Swedish are `iso-8859-1` and `utf-8`. On a modern system, `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 file.txt` should do it. On a crappy old PuTTY or ancient linux distro, `iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 file.txt` will.

Comment: @RicardoBranco, thanks, that was the missing command, I haven't had!

Comment: And at the same time @thatotherguy had right, cause the output was ISO-8859-2 --- but it worked with ISO-8859-1 as well!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments the solution was:

First execute:

```
chardet file.txt
```

to find out the character encoding.

Then:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 file.txt
```

to create the "translation".